# Adding authorization to a third-party web service

Tags: web-services, security, authentication, wsdl, mule

I have several third-party web services of which I only have their WSDL's. Currently they are only accessible in my internal network. I would like to expose those web services to the internet but, since they read/write sensitive information, I would need some sort of authentication mechanism in order to assure that only certain users are able to invoke them.

The idea is to expose exactly the same interface (same operations with the same parameters) but intercepting each invocation to check the security and then invoking the original web service if the authentication is valid or returning an exception or error message otherwise. I've been trying to use Mule ESB for the task abut I can't quite get there
Is this possible with mule? If not, how would i go about doing this? Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of security check do you envision? At HTTP level (like Basic Auth) or WS level (like WS-Security)?

Comment: Well, WS-Security would be ideal since its the whole point of it is providing security to SOAP WS. However, I reckon it is also harder to implement. On the other hand, Basic Auth is just too... basic. I was thinking about mutual authentication with SSL using self-signed certificates for both the client and the server. The problem now is just that I don't get how to put all this together on mule. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a web service proxy adding WS-Security to an unsecure target web service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
  xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf"
  xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security"
  xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.2/mule.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/3.2/mule-http.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/3.2/mule-cxf.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/3.2/mule-spring-security.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

<mule-ss:security-manager>
    <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider
        name="memory-provider" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
</mule-ss:security-manager>

<spring:beans>
    <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <ss:authentication-provider>
            <ss:user-service id="userService">
                <ss:user name="user" password="pass" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </ss:user-service>
        </ss:authentication-provider>
    </ss:authentication-manager>
    <cxf:security-manager-callback id="serverCallback" />
</spring:beans>

<flow name="secureStockQuoteWsProxy">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/sec-ws/stockquote"
        exchange-pattern="request-response">
        <cxf:proxy-service>
            <cxf:inInterceptors>
                <spring:bean
                    class="org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJInInterceptor" />
                <spring:bean
                    class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor">
                    <spring:constructor-arg>
                        <spring:map>
                            <spring:entry key="action" value="UsernameToken" />
                            <spring:entry key="passwordCallbackRef"
                                value-ref="serverCallback" />
                        </spring:map>
                    </spring:constructor-arg>
                </spring:bean>
            </cxf:inInterceptors>
        </cxf:proxy-service>
    </http:inbound-endpoint>

    <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx"
        exchange-pattern="request-response">
        <cxf:proxy-client enableMuleSoapHeaders="false"
            soapVersion="1.2" />
    </http:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

Comment: Thanks for that example. I'll play around with it to try to understand it. Cheers!

Comment: Ok, so i got it working perfectly with some minor modifications to the example posted. I tested it with SoapUI and it invokes the external WS when i pass along the credentials and returns a WS-Security exception when i dont. I know have a final question, when i try to generate a Java client for "http://localhost:8080/sec-ws/stockquote?wsdl" it internally redirects the look-up to the external WSDL. However, if i don't have direct access to this external WSDL the import process doesn't know where to find the WSDL and XSD's for the WS. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Not sure I get your question: is the remote WSDL accessible or not?

Comment: Sorry, i'll try to explain. The remote WSDL is accessible from the server where Mule is running. Let's say "http://ws.example/Example?wsdl", where "ws.example" internally redirects to a private IP. Additionally, that WSDL imports XSD schemas also from "ws.example". From Mule it all works like a charm. But, when an external client tries to create a WS Client for "http://muleServerIP:8080/sec-ws/stockquote?wsdl" Mule just passes that forward to ""http://ws.example/Example?wsdl" and since the external client can't see "ws.example" it returns an error saying it can't find the schemas.

Comment: The only way around this I've found so far is creating a local WSDL with no reference to "ws.example" and use that WSDL on the "wsdlLocation" of the "cxf:proxy-service" element. But that would mean generating that local WSDL for each of the external web services.

Comment: Mmmh, this is still unclear to me. Are you saying that only the soap:address locations are re-written in the proxied WSDL and not import URIs? That should work too. Any chance you pastebin relevant parts of the original WSDL and the one re-written by Mule?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happens. These are the important bits of the original WSDL: <definitions targetNamespace="http://impl.ws.sisloc.loctech.com/" name="WSVehiculo">
<import namespace="http://ws.sisloc.loctech.com/" location="http://ws.clocator.net:80/wsSisLoc/WSVehiculo?wsdl=1"/>. And the <soap:address location="http://ws.clocator.net:80/wsSisLoc/WSVehiculo"/>

Comment: And now, this are the same bits but from the WSDL re-written by mule: <definitions name="WSVehiculo" targetNamespace="http://impl.ws.sisloc.loctech.com/">
<import location="http://ws.clocator.net:80/wsSisLoc/WSVehiculo?wsdl=1" namespace="http://ws.sisloc.loctech.com/"></import>. And the adress re-written correctly: <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/wsSisLoc/WSVehiculo"/>.

Comment: Note of course that i changed "http://localhost:8080/sec-ws/stockquote" from the example to "http://localhost:8080/wsSisLoc/WSVehiculo".

Comment: Any chance to fix the remote WSDL so it uses relative paths for its import elements instead of absolute ones? If not, I see two options: attempt to rewrite the imports in a custom CXF or Mule interceptor in the response phase ; or open a JIRA ticket with MuleSoft to ask that CXF proxies rewrite all URIs and not just the soap:address locations.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think i'll go with using CFX's Java2WS to generate all the WSDLs with soap address "http://localhost:8080/wsSisLoc/WSVehiculo" and inline schemas. I'll open a ticket on MuleSoft anyways to let them know about the issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?wsdl gives the same result. So you could test it there. Maybe the problem lies with .net services.

Anyway, for now I made a successful proxy with the webservice pattern. Now I am still working on transforming a response. Not with much success because Mule keeps giving me a ReleasingInputStream as response.